How to total time duration for an arbitrary number of tracked tasks in Excel?
I am using Microsoft 365 Excel and am trying to create a spreadsheet to track time charged to different charge numbers on a daily basis. It will never be the case that a charge spans midnight.
There are an arbitrary number of charge numbers that may be charged, and any given charge number may have multiple time periods associated with it.
I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will adapt automatically to any number of charge numbers and to any number of charges to a given charge number.
Here is an example of the table I've created to track the time I spend on various charge numbers throughout a day:

To illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, I have manually created a table summarizing my time as I need it to be summarized (by charge number):

Since the first table is formatted as a table, I can simply right-click on the Total row and select Insert and a new row will be added and the formulas in columns Duration and Cumulative Total Duration will be copied down. I need only enter values in columns Start, Stop, and Charge Number. Everything in this table will automatically update as desired.
The goal is to get the second table to update automatically when I update the first table. Here is an example with lines added to what was presented above and the automatic update I'd like to see happen in the second table:


I'm thinking a pivot table may be the way to go, but I have this far been able to get that to work.
How may I get the second table to update automatically as well when I add a new line to the first table?
Update to Add Info Requested in a Comment

Show your work so far -- what formula used to find duration, to add items for same job #, etc.

Columns Start and Stop are are formatted as Time 1:30 PM. Columns Duration (first table), Cumulative Total Duration, and Duration (second table) are formatted as Custom h:mm.
The formula for Duration (first table) is simply =[@Stop]-[@Start]. (Again, a midnight boundary will never be crossed, so this is sufficient.)
The formula for Cumulative Total Duration is =C2+IF(ISTEXT(G1), 0, G1). The call to ISTEXT() prevents the header row from being "added" in.
There are no formulas in the second table (i.e., times for the same job). I manually placed the values into that table and manually calculated the totals to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish in an automated manner.

I have figured out how to do this using a pivot table. In addition to what's shown above in the desired output table, I have also added a field that shows the total duration for a charge number in decimal hours.
The source table and the desired output table are shown here:


The pivot table is defined as follows:

Here, Sum of Duration as Decimal is a calculated field defined as 24 * Duration with the format set to Number with 1 decimal place of precision.

If you have 365, you can also do this using a formula:
(Assumes your data is in a Table)
=LET(
    d, Table1,
    u, SORT(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(d, 4))),
    a, BYROW(
        u,
        LAMBDA(arr, SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(d, arr = CHOOSECOLS(d, 4)), 3)))
    ),
    VSTACK({"Charge Number", "Duration"}, HSTACK(u, a))
)

Since your data is in a Table, and I am referencing that table, if you add rows to the table, the formula will auto-adjust
